# What is the meaning of 岩圭?

Tags: meaning

I am setting up a new company.  Is the name 岩圭 a good choice or does it make sense as a name ?  What is the meaning of 岩圭?  I found somebody with that name in the internet. Is that a common or popular name.

For your information, my company is selling live fish.

Thank you

Comment: Can I ask, how did you come up with this name if you don't know what it means?  What made you decide to name a company 岩圭?

Comment: Not to be rude to the fish-selling person, but I'm really surprised that this post didn't get put on hold. He didn't do any research, nor was he encouraged to. All it would have taken is a simple dictionary search to find that the characters mean 'rock' and 'gemstone'. I see the moderators get on to people who DID show some research, and they still put them on hold.

Comment: Your dictionary cannot answer "does it make sense as a name" type questions...

Comment: @PinkuNoUsagi Closing a question should be community-driven. Moderators can close a question, if they think that the community wants it to be closed (e.g. because the community has decided on a particular policy for closing, say, translation questions). That said, the community still hasn't cast any close votes. If you want to discuss this you can do so on meta.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also very curious how come you came up with 岩圭, but well, the reason can be anything. There was even a person who wanted to use a rare Japanese word because [she saw it in a dream](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36347/5010) :) Maybe you saw 岩圭 in a book written by your favorite novelist?

- 岩圭 is not common nor popular as a person name. I don't know anyone whose name is 岩圭.
- 岩圭 is not in this [list of top 4500 Japanese surnames](https://myoji-yurai.net/prefectureRanking.htm?pref=0).
- That being said, both 岩 and 圭 are commonly-used kanji in names, so 岩圭 doesn't look that weird to me. I won't be surprised if I saw a real traditional Japanese company with this name. It's at least far better than [these ridiculous tattoos](https://www.buzzfeed.com/ellievhall/ridiculous-chinese-character-tattoos-translated?utm_term=.bymrnyr9D#.ss5jmXj7d).
- As for the meaning, very few would ever care because it's a proper noun. 岩圭 is 岩圭 — just as Smith is Smith and not a metal craftsman, Johnson is Johnson and not a son of John. But if you insist, 岩 means *rock*. 圭 is a kanji which was used to refer to a *gemstone* or *orb*, but it is now recognized as just another kanji used in names. Semantically it has nothing to do with live fish, but that doesn't matter.
- The most likely reading of 岩圭 is いわけい (Iwakei), but other readings are possible. See: [Is it correct to read 黒川 as くろかわ or is くろがわ correct?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42989/5010)

In conclusion, if you have a good reason, it's possible to name a company 岩圭. I can't tell if it's a good choice or not, though.

Answer (score 1):

"岩圭(Iwa kei)" isn't in a Japanese dictionary. Japanese understand that "岩{いわ}" means rock. There is a name "圭{けい}子{こ}," and I guess the Kanji "圭" has positive image, but I don't know the Kanji "圭{けい}" itself as something meaningfull.

You can name your company "岩{いわ}圭{けい}," but we Japanese don't understand it. Some Japanese might ask you "What does it mean?"

Your business is seling live fresh, so it might be better to find the name using "魚," "鮮 (this comes from "新鮮(fresh)"," or "清(pure, clear)."

Comment: I am not Japanese, but I don't understand it either. You mean not "we Japanese", but "Japanese speakers". The original question is of course bizarre.

Comment: Hi Brian、分かりました。これからはそうします。